# Fastest way to delete/extract a submatrix from a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a square matrix that is NxN (N is usually >500). It is constructed using a numpy array.

I need to extract a new matrix that has the i-th column and row removed from this matrix. The new matrix is (N-1)x(N-1).

I am currently using the following code to extract this matrix:

```
            new_mat = np.delete(old_mat,idx_2_remove,0)
            new_mat = np.delete(old_mat,idx_2_remove,1)
```

I have also tried to use:

```
row_indices = [i for i in range(0,idx_2_remove)]
row_indices += [i for i in range(idx_2_remove+1,N)]
col_indices = row_indices
rows = [i for i in row_indices for j in col_indices]
cols = [j for i in row_indices for j in col_indices]

old_mat[(rows, cols)].reshape(len(row_indices), len(col_indices))
```

But I found this is slower than using `np.delete()` in the former. The former is still quite slow for my application.

Is there a faster way to accomplish what I want?

Edit 1:
It seems the following is even faster than the above two, but not by much:

```
new_mat = old_mat[row_indices,:][:,col_indices]
```

Comment: If it is only around `500x500`, the time copying is usually negligible. For bigger matrices, I believe creating an empty array and copying 4 slices onto it should be fairly fast.

Comment: I would say `500x500` is on the small side. The largest would be in the `50,000x50,000`. Most cases I'm working with are probably around `10,000x10,000`. What do you think about the method in the edit? i.e., ```new_mat = old_mat[row_indices,:][:,col_indices]
```

Comment: Depending on vectorizing stuff, using `slice` instead of fancy index *should* be faster, but that needs to be benchmarked. Anyway, indexing twice is likely going to take twice much time, you might want to at least broadcast these two indexing together, like `old_mat[row_indices[:,None],col_indices]`.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks! I have never tried `slice` before, but i will take a look.

Comment: I am getting an error using `old_mat[row_indices[:,None],col_indices]`. It is saying `new_mat = old_mat[row_idx[:,None],col_idx]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: Oh forgot to mention `row_idx` also have to be a numpy array. It's a good practice not to mix python and numpy array

Comment: Any deletion requires building a new array.  It isn't so much a matter of removing things from the source, but rather creating a new array from the pieces you want to keep.  `np.delete` uses difference approaches depending on your indexing.  It may concatenate right and left pieces.  It may use a mask to extract the keepers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 alternatives I quickly wrote:

Repeated `delete`:

```
def foo1(arr, i):
    return np.delete(np.delete(arr, i, axis=0), i, axis=1)
```

Maximal use of slicing (may need some edge checks):

```
def foo2(arr,i):
    N = arr.shape[0]
    res = np.empty((N-1,N-1), arr.dtype)
    res[:i, :i] = arr[:i, :i]
    res[:i, i:] = arr[:i, i+1:]
    res[i:, :i] = arr[i+1:, :i]
    res[i:, i:] = arr[i+1:, i+1:]
    return res
```

Advanced indexing:

```
def foo3(arr,i):
    N = arr.shape[0]
    idx = np.r_[:i,i+1:N]
    return arr[np.ix_(idx, idx)]
```

Test that they work:

```
In [874]: x = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
In [875]: np.allclose(foo1(x,5),foo2(x,5))
Out[875]: True
In [876]: np.allclose(foo1(x,5),foo3(x,5))
Out[876]: True
```

Compare timings:

```
In [881]: timeit foo1(arr,100).shape
4.98 ms ± 190 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [882]: timeit foo2(arr,100).shape
526 µs ± 1.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [883]: timeit foo3(arr,100).shape
2.21 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the slicing is fastest, even if the code is longer.  It looks like `np.delete` works like `foo3`, but one dimension at a time.